# How can I start cocos2d-iPhone development?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d game development. I want to know how to get started. Is any special installation needed for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [the cocos2d-iPhone website.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).  You can download cocos2d-iPhone [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download). Finally, [here is](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/) the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out Kobold2D here: 
http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/Home

To get started there is nothing wrong with the Cocos2D Project templates (there is a shell script in the official download that you can use to install them). But once you want to upgrade your Cocos2D version in such a project you will notice that it's getting quite complicated. Kobold2D should make this much simpler, I think it has an updater tool.

I also can recommend the book by Steffen Itterheim which is also featured on the Kobold2D website. I don't know if the second edition is out yet, if it isn't I suggest you wait for that.

The official Cocos2D forum also is a great place to get started. Check out this thread: 
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/737